# Error message regarding Package-Manager

Tags: 16.04, package-management

I always find this error message.. How to fix this problem? Please help.

[image]

Comment: Try going to a command prompt and typing in `sudo apt install -f`

Comment: Try updating your system after doing what @Alex2012 has suggested. Perhaps you don;t update as often as you should.

Comment: Try running sudo apt-get --reinstall install ttf-mscorefonts-installer

Answer (score 0):

try

```
sudo dpkg --configure -a
```

and then

```
sudo apt install -f
```